# Firefox: BitmapData Handle?

Tags: image, firefox, bash, browser, handle

I have heard that it is possible to get a bitmap/image handle of the webpage being viewed on a firefox browser. I have been researching for a bit and couldn't not find anything.

So I am hoping if anyone knows how to do this, preferable via the command line (bash, any other shell on Linux).

To be honest, any browser that I could do this on is fine as long as its simple and on the shell!

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one option: ImageMagick has an [import](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php) command that will take a screenshot of any (X server) window from the command line. If you don't want the entire window you can specify a cropping area.

Comment: I have been having a look at this option too, but I think the firefox is option is better. I could run Xvfb on my server and take a screenshot of a window but I don't want to go in the mess of identifying that window and guessing when to take the screenshot as I do not know when the page has loaded. I just wanted to run and point firefox to a webpage and get whatever it has as an image.

Comment: I have had to opt for an XVFB solution as everything else I have found was written a long time ago and are very hard to get going!